# Ignite cache is empty after save?

Tags: spark-streaming, rdd, ignite

My data pipeline is following: `Kafka` => perform some calculations => load resulting pairs into `Ignite cache` => print it out

```
 SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("MainApplication");
 JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
 JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, Durations.seconds(10));
 JavaIgniteContext<String, Float> igniteContext = new JavaIgniteContext<>(sc, PATH, false);

 JavaDStream<Message> dStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
         streamingContext,
         LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
         ConsumerStrategies.<String, Message>
                 Subscribe(Collections.singletonList(TOPIC), kafkaParams)
 )
         .map(ConsumerRecord::value);

 JavaPairDStream<String, Message> pairDStream =
         dStream.mapToPair(message -> new Tuple2<>(message.getName(), message));

 JavaPairDStream<String, Float> pairs = pairDStream
         .combineByKey(new CreateCombiner(), new MergeValue(), new MergeCombiners(), new HashPartitioner(10))
         .mapToPair(new ToPairTransformer());

 JavaIgniteRDD<String, Float> myCache = igniteContext.fromCache(new CacheConfiguration<>());

  // I know that we put something here:
  pairDStream.foreachRDD((VoidFunction<JavaPairRDD<String, Float>>) myCache::savePairs);

  // But I can't see anything here:
  myCache.foreach(tuple2 -> System.out.println("In cache: " + tuple2._1() + " = " + tuple2._2()));

  streamingContext.start();
  streamingContext.awaitTermination();
  streamingContext.stop();
  sc.stop();
```

But this code prints nothing.. Why?

Why `Ignite cache` is empty even after `savePairs`?

What can be wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you're looping through `myCache` before you've started streaming any data into it? Do you get the same result if you put your foreach loop before the `sc.stop()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, it looks like that `pairDStream.foreachRDD(...)` is a lazy operation and has no any affect at least before you start streaming context `streamingContext.start()`. 
On the other hand, `myCache.foreach(...)` is eager operation and you perform it on actually empty cache. 
So, try to put `myCache.foreach(...)` after streaming context start. Or even after termination.